# Visual C++ Express 2010 suddenly won't accept #includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, visual-c++-2010-express

I'm working with an API which has `#define`ed all their include files. I'm developing in Visual C++ 2010 Express, and it's been working fine up till now.

I was adding a new cpp-file to the project, and accidentally added a "Windows Form" instead. VC warned me that my project was not using CLR at the moment, did I really want to? I clicked no, and added the file as intended. After that, however, my project no longer compiles.

The code looks basically like this:

**api_header.h**:

```
#define DEFINED_HEADER_NAME "path/to/header/file.h"
```

**stdhpf.h**:

```
#include DEFINED_HEADER_NAME
```

As I said, worked fine for a long time. Now I get this:

> error C2006: `'#include'` : expected a filename, found `'identifier'`
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: `''`: No such file or directory

What is causing this? I found some post that said it was because of having turned on precompiled headers, but I checked `Project properties > Configuration properties > C/C++ / Precompiled headers`, and it's off (I mention the setting path since I'm new to VS, there might be more than one way to do it...).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem almost certainly lies in the order in which the two statements are pre-processed, rather than having anything to do with inadvertently adding a Windows Form object.

[This knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115857) suggests:

> The problem is in using a defined constant to specify an include file in the #include directive. The directive is being processed before the macro is completely expanded, resulting in the error.

The second error seems to confirm this, as it indicates the pre-processor is searching for an include file with an empty name:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of your include files has changed. Perhaps Visual Studio inserted a `#include "stdhpf.h"` somewhere ahead of your `#include "api_header.h"`.

Answer (score 0):

Disable precompiled headers. It should helps.